# what does this "int logprintf( const char* ptr, ... )" do?

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I have an old C++ code that has this line of code:

```
int logprintf( const char* ptr, ... );
```

and I am not sure what does it do exactly? should I change the code in order to be able to compile the code with new versions of the compiler?! does anybody have an idea? any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This should compile with every C++ compiler.It is a function prototype. It declares something like custom log/debug method like this one:https://code.google.com/p/libnfc/source/browse/libnfc/log-printf.c?r=fef6517e27e4385b0254d13c9b27095734553bbc&spec=svnfef6517e27e4385b0254d13c9b27095734553bbc

Comment: it looks like a general logging variable arguement function, eg. you'd do something like `logprintf(L"error code:%d, msg:%s", errorCode, errorStr.c_str())`, when you say change it why does this not compile? the ellipsis `...` allows a variable number of params to be passed

Comment: That's a function declaration, also known as a function prototype. It declares as function named `logprintf` that takes a variable number of arguments and returns an integer. Besides that, what problems do you have with the declaration?

Comment: This should compile with any c/c++ compiler.

Answer (score 1):

That's just C code and any compiler made since the 1980s should be able to handle it. The definition is of a [varidic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function), or "varargs" in C parlance.

What that does is declare a method signature, nothing more. Presumably somewhere else, either in a library you link in or in a C or C++ file you compile there's a matching implementation.

Most `printf`-style functions do not have a fixed number of arguments. This is what the ellipsis `...` represents, zero or more arbitrary arguments go there.